# Windows 7 - Keep folder view settings

Tags: view, windows-7, directory

If I go to any folder like `C:\temp` and select Detailed View and sort by name, all folder in my system will have this configuration. But I don't want this. I would like that `C:\temp` has that configuration, but to keep the folder view configuration for all other folders as they were before I change the view of `C:\temp`.

I remember that in Win XP that is possible. But it seems to not be possible in Windows 7. Am I right?

*UPDATE*

I just figured out that folders outside from Documents can have different type of visualization. I think the problem is how to keep individual configuration view for folders inside Documents.

Comment: Off topic, should be on SuperUser

Comment: Please take a few minutes to review the [help] pages topics for what questions are (and are not) on topic here. Thanks.

Comment: But this question is still open here, in SuperUser and somewhere else maybe. Unfortunately, it seems to not be possible to do what we want. Thanks everyone :)